# How to change the available color palettes in MS Excel's "Chart Styles"

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, charts, colors

When you make a chart in Excel 2011 and greater, there are a few options for setting the default color palette. Is there a way to add new color palette options or modify one of the existing palettes? To match company colors, for instance.

[image: Color Palette selector]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Click on Page layout> Colors > Customize Colors
2. The Create New Theme Colors will appear.
3. Select/Change the colors for the different options under Theme colors.
4. Give your theme a name, click Save.
5. Click on Page layout> Colors, select the newly created layout for your chart to change its colors based on the seletions you made.

[image]